# How to get number of elements with certain class that occur before current element in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to index `tr` of a table with class `sLot` and `sLineitem`

Lineitem comes under Lot in hierarchy.

```html
    <table style="width:100%;" id="summarytable">
        <tr class="sLot">
            <td>Lot1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sLineitem">
            <td>Lineitem1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sLot">
            <td>Lot2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want this to look like :

```
1   Lot1
    Lot1 desc
1.1 Lineitem1
2   Lot2
2.1 Lineitem1 under lot2
```

Assume, using table is the only option.

Comment: its hard to understand the question because your "I want this to look like block" does not match the code given - please clarify so we can help

Comment: `Lineitem comes under Lot in hierarchy` - false. No such classes, similar classes are in same level in hierarchy. `I want this to look like` what have you tried?

Comment: Nevermind guys, DGS has understood the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```js
//Add the extra column to all rows
$('tr').prepend($('<td />', {
  class: 'srno'
}));

$('.sLot').each(function(i, el) {
  //get the index of the current sLot element
  var index = i + 1;
  //set the current sLot rows index text 
  $(el).find('.srno').text(index);
  //find all rows in between this and the next sLot that are .sLineitem and set their text
  $(el).nextUntil('.sLot').filter('.sLineitem').each(function(j, el2) {
    $(el2).find('.srno').text(index + '.' + (j + 1));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;" id="summarytable">
  <tr class="sLot">
    <td>Lot1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sLineitem">
    <td>Lineitem1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sLot">
    <td>Lot2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4p0sw3fy/1/

Comment: Inserting td in selected rows while leaving out others might botch up design. Can you change it to add extra td with class='srno' in every tr and then setting text of lot and lineitem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gx6sefr6/2/ is working for you. It is a little different from your question though,

Comment: Yes this one is working for me.. but I will have to make some changes to start numbering from class `sSection`. Which means there will be three levels. `sSection--->sLot--->sLotLineItem`

I can not demand this from you since i did not mention it in the question. But if you can explain your code a bit it would be easier to modify.  I am marking your answer anyways.